# C# WCF Setup a Service and a Client for OASIS WS 1.1 X509 certificate token profile

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, ssl

I would like to setup a module which will communicate with other modules remotely acting both as a service and as a client. The communcation should go in SOAP 1.2 and it should use OASIS WSS 1.1, and X.509 certificate token profile. 
[OASIS WSS 1.1 X.509 specs](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/v1.1/wss-v1.1-spec-os-x509TokenProfile.pdf)

I already made a development certificate using makecert and it is trusted already.

Since the module is essentially C# based, all settings are given in code. So far I got the following service code:

The code for the binding:

```
System.ServiceModel.Channels.AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement asbe = new AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement();
        asbe.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity11WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12;

        asbe.InitiatorTokenParameters = new System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.X509SecurityTokenParameters { InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToRecipient };
        asbe.RecipientTokenParameters = new System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.X509SecurityTokenParameters { InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToRecipient };
        asbe.MessageProtectionOrder = System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageProtectionOrder.SignBeforeEncrypt;

        asbe.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Strict;
        asbe.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;
        asbe.IncludeTimestamp = false;
        asbe.SetKeyDerivation(false);
        asbe.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic128Rsa15;
        asbe.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.Signed.Add(new UserNameSecurityTokenParameters());
        asbe.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.Signed.Add(new X509SecurityTokenParameters());

        CustomBinding myBinding = new CustomBinding();
        myBinding.Elements.Add(asbe);
        myBinding.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap12, Encoding.UTF8));

        HttpsTransportBindingElement httpsBindingElement = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
        httpsBindingElement.RequireClientCertificate = true;
        myBinding.Elements.Add(httpsBindingElement);
```

The code for the behaviour:

```
//Then initiate the service host
        _Host = new ServiceHost(typeof(TClass), baseAddress);

        //Add the service endpoint we defined
        _Host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(TInterface), _Binding, typeof(TInterface).ToString());//BindingHelper.GetUserNameBinding(), "");
        //Set searching the certificate
        _Host.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "MyServerCert");
        _Host.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
        _Host.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
        //Allow the metadata spreading
        ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        smb.HttpsGetEnabled = true;
        smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        _Host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
        ServiceDebugBehavior sdb = new ServiceDebugBehavior();
        sdb.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = false; //Should only provide the endpoint property (GP WS-Message profile specs)
        //Add the appropriate endpoint
        if (baseAddress.AbsoluteUri.Contains("https"))
            _Host.AddServiceEndpoint(
              typeof(IMetadataExchange),
              MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpsBinding(),
              "mex");
        else
            _Host.AddServiceEndpoint(
                typeof(IMetadataExchange),
                 MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(),
            "mex");
```

On the client side I use the same code to create the binding, plus I use the following behavior:

```
channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<T>(bindIn, serviceAddress);
        if (wsFeature != null)
        {
            channelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Remove(typeof(ClientCredentials));
            channelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(wsFeature);
            channelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "MyServerCert");
                channelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetScopedCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "MyServerCert",serviceAddress.Uri);

        }
        _ProxiObject = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

Here basically the behavior wsFeature is a simple class doing practically nothing (just implements blank functions for IEndpointBehavior). 
I have both service and client on the same machine at  `https://localhost.:8084/testhosting4`, and even though both service and client are successfully created I only got the famous "An error occurred while making the HTTP request to `https://localhost.:8084/testhosting4`. etc." error.

I already managed to connect via an unsecure channel with the module (BasicHttpBinding - no security) and exchange messages, so I am sure that I make a mistake in defining the binding or assigning credentials. Obviously, I browsed a lot here already, but couldn't come up with a working solution.
This is the first time I meet WCF and X509 and I'm not in secure communications at all either. So plenty of occasions to make a mistake. Please point out those which I've made.
Thank you!